# Creating a path and running specific commands on that directory

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR4Ij.png)Ex.

```
$ap = Get-location "cd c:\osit\bin\acf"
$ap ./acf -t
```

However its not working. Error that its not a commandlet.

Because `acf -t` only works on that directory thats why I need to create a script will automatically call the directory and run that `acf -t`

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Get-Location` part, `cd` will work just fine on its own:

```
cd c:\osit\bin\acf
.\acf.cmd -t
```

Comment: Dont work. Tried in CMD no luck as well.. 

./acf : The term './acf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ ./acf -t
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./acf:String) [], CommandNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @JpValencia Is the binary in `C:\osit\bin` or `C:\osit\bin\acf`? Also, try `.\acf.exe` instead.

Comment: its in C:\osit\bin\acf\  | on that path acf -t only works

Comment: I added a screenshot of the path

Comment: @JpValencia from the screenshot it looks like `acf` is not a binary, but a `.cmd` file, updated the answer

Comment: `cd` is an alias for `Set-Location`. It is a best practice not to use aliases in scripts. Better to use `Set-Location -Path 'C:\osit\bin\acf'`.

Comment: Hello Guys!

It worked now. Using the codes below. However, my question is how can I set the location back to normal path or default path after running those commands. Set-Location -Path 'C:\user\?' somethhing like this?

Set-Location -Path 'C:\osit\bin\acf'

$av = .\acf -t

$av

Answer (score 0):

Try this (comments begin with a `#`; without is the "code")

```
# save the current path to variable $path
$path = Get-Location

# change path to executable
Set-Location -Path 'c:\osit\bin\acf'

# execute programme
.\act.cmd -t

# change back to the path we came from
Set-Location -Path $path
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Case Closed Now :) Good Work hehe!